# In a vectorized way in numpy: Cutting out chunks of data (of different sizes) conditionally dependent on whats inside the chunk

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a vector of integers (a 1D numpy array) that looks like:

```
8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 99, 8, 1, 1
```

(In a vectorized way,) I want to filter out all of the data between 8's that contain at least one 99 value.

So in this example, the data I want to cut out is listed in bold:

```
8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 99, 8, 1, 1
```

(i.e., it's data that's inbetween the 8's that contains at least one 99)

So if I made a boolean mask to crop out this data it would look like:

```
Data: 8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 99, 8, 1, 1
Mask: T, T, T, T, F,  F, F, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, F,  F,  F, T, T, T
```

And data after cropping look like:

```
Data(Mask) = 8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 1
```

I can come up with vectorized code that can do this if there is a guaranteed equal spacing between the 8's. Here's that code:

```
inputRaw = np.array([8, 2, 3, 2, 99, 2, 8, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
inputPartitioned = np.reshape(inputRaw, (3, 6))
# reshaping it into an array of the form: np.array([[8, 2, 3, 2, 99, 2], [8, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2], [8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
selectedSections = np.logical_not(np.any(inputPartitioned>8, axis=1))
outputPartitioned = inputPartitioned[selectedSections]
outputFlattened = outputPartitioned.flatten()
```

One extra thing that I need is a mask or index that tells me (in the original indices) the data that was cropped. (I need this because I have a second array I want to keep track of that has shared indices with the first array). I can code this mask (assumming equal spacing between the 8's) like so:

```
inputIndex = np.arange(inputRaw.size)
inputIndexPartitioned =  np.reshape(inputIndex, (3, 6))
outputPartitionedIndex = inputIndexPartitioned[selectedSections]
outputFlattenedIndex = outputPartitionedIndex.flatten()
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in a vectorized way in the case where there's unequal spacing between the 8's.

Any ideas? These arrays are very long, so solutions that work fast for large arrays are helpful. Also, I'm fairly confident that these "99's" will always immediately after an 8, so maybe that might be helpful information in making the algorithm.

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there is a better solution to begin with. How is the original array created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized one for a generic case when the `99's` occur between two `8's` and all those elements between those two `8's` are then to be removed/masked-out -

```
def vectorized1_app(a):
    m1 = a==8
    m2 = a==99
    d = m1.cumsum()
    occ_mask = np.bincount(d,m2)<1
    if m1.argmax() > m2.argmax():
        occ_mask[0] = ~occ_mask[0]

    if m1[::-1].argmax() > m2[::-1].argmax():
        occ_mask[-1] = ~occ_mask[-1]
    mask = occ_mask[d]
    return mask
```

**Approach #2**

We could also make use of JIT-compiled [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) code for the specific case of `8's` and `99's` in sequence -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba1(a, mask_out):
    N = len(a)
    fill = False
    last8_index = 0
    for i in range(N-1):
        if a[i]==8:
            if a[i+1]==99:
                fill = True
            else:
                fill = False
            last8_index = i

        if fill:        
            mask_out[i] = False

    return mask_out, last8_index

def numba1_app(a):
    N = len(a)
    mask = np.ones(N, dtype=np.bool)
    mask, last8_index = numba1(a, mask)
    if a[-1]!=8:
        mask[last8_index:] = True
    return mask
```

**Approach #2-B**

Some marginal perf. boost with pushing the last step of last element check to numba-part, like so -

```
@njit
def numba2(a, mask_out):
    N = len(a)
    fill = False
    last8_index = 0
    for i in range(N-1):
        if a[i]==8:
            if a[i+1]==99:
                fill = True
            else:
                fill = False
            last8_index = i

        if fill:        
            mask_out[i] = False

    if a[N-1]!=8:
        for i in range(last8_index,N-1):
            mask_out[i] = True

    return mask_out

def numba2_app(a):
    return numba2(a, np.ones(len(a), dtype=np.bool))
```

Note that the outputs off the posted approaches are mask, so that masking the input array with these would give us comparable results to `Data(Mask)`.

---

**Special case : Mask out until first `8`, keep after last `8`**

We could modify app#1 with two ways to do so -

App#1-Mod#1 -

```
m1 = a==8
m2 = a==99
d = m1.cumsum()
occ_mask = np.bincount(d,m2)<1
occ_mask[0] = False
mask = occ_mask[d]
```

If you have to modify the case such that you wish to mask after last `8` too, simply do : `occ_mask[-1] = False`.

App#1-Mod#2 -

```
m1 = a==8
m2 = a==99
d = m1.cumsum().clip(min=1)
occ_mask = np.bincount(d,m2)<1
mask = occ_mask[d]
```

If you have to modify the case such that you wish to mask after last `8` too, do : `m1c = m1.cumsum(); d = m1c.clip(min=1, max=m1c.max()-1)`.

Comment: Ah the famous Divakar! I always am impressed by your answers. Thank you for your answer. I've never heard of numba, so thanks for the recommendation - I'll try to learn some of it when I have time. For attempt 1, I found Yoni's answer a bit easier to understand. Is there any "functional" difference between the two? Do you recommend  your method in particular (maybe functions like bincount() are often useful?)

Comment: @StevenSagona Well `bincount` is just a compact way to get count based on bins and hence detect presence based on those `99's`. If you are asking for functional difference between Yoni's one and my app#1, I see one difference and that comes with the additional if-else I have at the end to cover for border cases. So, say the input is `[1, 99, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 2, 1]`. I would think the first two elements would get `T's` in the output mask and similarly last 4 would also get `T's` because for those the "island" pattern of `[8,99,....8]` is not there.

Comment: @StevenSagona  The results based on that seems different on mine vs on Yoni's. So, I guess I would have to ask you - What's the expected result for such a case?

Comment: Ah okay I understand! I was not careful and did not specify what I wanted for the edge-cases. In my case I technically would like [1, 1, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 2, 1] to become [8, 2, 2, 2] (cutting off data before the first 8) and [1, 1, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 2, 1 8 1 1] becoming [8, 2, 2, 2 8, 1, 1] (leaving data after the last 8). Sorry about the ambiguity!

Comment: I think I'll be able to modify the code you wrote to cover that specific "edge case".

Comment: @StevenSagona Updated with `Special case ` section at the end. Hope I got the idea right this time.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (I've avoided the "fairly confident" part, so it will run even if 99 is not immediately after an 8).

```
import numpy as np

in_arr = np.array([8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 99, 8, 1, 1])

mask_8 = in_arr == 8
mask_8_cumsum = np.cumsum(mask_8)
print(mask_8_cumsum)
>>> [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5]

unique_inds = np.unique(mask_8_cumsum[in_arr == 99])
print(unique_inds)
>>> [2 4]

final_mask = ~np.isin(mask_8_cumsum, unique_inds)
final_data = in_arr[final_mask]
print(final_mask)
>>> [ True  True  True  True False False False False False False  True  True
  True  True False False False  True  True  True]

print(final_data)
>>> [8 1 1 2 8 2 2 2 8 1 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was the easiest answer to understand so thanks a lot! I'm torn between rewarding the bounty between you and divakar.

Answer (score 1):

Another numpy approach:

```
def pp(a):                                            
    m8 = a==8
    m99 = a==99
    m = m8|m99
    i = m.nonzero()[0]
    c8 = m8[i]
    i = i[c8]
    n8 = np.count_nonzero(c8)
    if n8 == 0:
        return np.ones(a.size,bool)
    if c8[-1]:
        d8 = np.empty(n8,bool)
        d8[-1] = False
        d8[:-1] = ~c8[1:][c8[:-1]]
    else:
        d8 = ~c8[1:][c8[:-1]]
    d8[1:]^=d8[:-1]
    m8[i] = d8
    m8[0]^=True
    return np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(m8)
```

For example:

```
a = np.array([8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 99, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 99, 99, 8, 1, 1])
a[pp(a)]
# array([8, 1, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go through it in some time to learn.